# Connecting to language server over websocket

Tags: vscode-extensions

Context: I am trying to write an extension to vscode that will connect to a language server that is already running. The reason I want to do this is so I can run the language server in my IDE, and attach a debugger to it.

I am trying to connect using websockets. This is the code I have in my extension:

```js
import * as vscode from 'vscode';
import WebSocket from 'ws';
import { TextDecoder } from 'util';

// Import the language client, language client options and server options from VSCode language client.
import { LanguageClient } from 'vscode-languageclient';

// Name of the launcher class which contains the main.
const main: string = 'com.ajanuary.ashlang.lsp.AsLangLanguageServerLauncher';

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    console.log('Congratulations, your extension "ashlang" is now active!');

    const ws = new WebSocket(`ws://localhost:5000/`);
    const connection = WebSocket.createWebSocketStream(ws);

    connection.on("data", function (chunk) {
        console.log(new TextDecoder().decode(chunk));
     });

    let disposable = new LanguageClient('ashLS', 'Ash Language Server',
    () => Promise.resolve({
        reader: connection,
        writer: connection,
    }), {
        documentSelector: [{ scheme: 'file', language: 'ash' }]
    }).start();
    context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
}

// this method is called when your extension is deactivated
export function deactivate() { 
    console.log('Your extension "ashlang" is now deactivated!');
}
```

The data handler prints out:

```json
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":0,"result":{"capabilities":{"textDocumentSync":1,"completionProvider":{}}}}
```

So I know it is able to talk to my server and read the response. However, the extension doesn't seem to handle the response because it never sends any more messages.

How do I get it to read and process the messages from the websocket correctly? Or is there a better way of tackling the problem of developing the languageserver in an IDE?

Comment: Modify your language server to hang about 5-10 seconds (and report its process ID) when launching, so that you can attach the debugger after VS Code initializes the process. That's how I debug the projects I am working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the Content-Length header wasn't being sent. I assumed the lsp library I was using would take care of that, but it wasn't.

The message should have been:

```
Content-Length: 97


{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":0,"result":{"capabilities":{"textDocumentSync":1,"completionProvider":{}}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar scenario and I tried to use your code, but I don't even see any output from the data handler. All I see is a bunch of errors in the console like:
`connection to server is erroring. Shutting down server.`
followed by
`Error: Client is not running and can't be stopped. It's current state is: starting`

I was just trying to modify the example from https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-server-extension-guide

UPD: I made it to the point where it calls my language server `connect()` method but doesn't send any other requests and eventually times out. Wondering if anyone can give me any pointers on how to troubleshoot it.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34703937)